# Cannot configure rgee R package properly with ee_install()

Tags: r, configuration, miniconda, google-earth-engine, rgee

I've searched for tutorials to help configure the package in my PC, and I've found this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fDhRL_LBdQ

I executed every part of the code interactively with the tutorial, but when I run `ee_install()` (after installing miniconda with `py_discover_config()` and other packages previously, such as `reticulate`), but it keeps me returning an error saying that anaconda is mandatory for the package since I'm a windows user.

Here is the error I get:

```
Error in ee_install_set_pyenv_env(py_env = py_env, py_path = python_path, : Windows users must install miniconda/anaconda to use rgee. The use of a Python environment is mandatory.
```

I've just installed Anaconda (full version with navigator) and I set a new python environment called "py2r" and tried to use the function `ee_install_set_pyenv()`, passing the path to the environment created through Anaconda Navigator (which has a python.exe) as paremeter to py_path and the name "py2r" as paremeter for py_env arg. And yet, it didn't work.

What am I missing?

In case you want to take a look at the code, I can provide it, but I don't think it's necessary because is a simple test script that follows as I described.

Thanks for your attention and congratulations for the library, it will be very usefull for me at work!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the ee_install() problems bypassing them and doing every passage manually. It will require no more then 10 mins and you will probably fix the installation problems. You can find and follow the manual installation with this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-k6wNL2hlo